# Keyboard Animation Curve as Int

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

I am trying to get the UIAnimationCurve of the keyboard, if it exists. The code I am using is below:

```
if let kbCurve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? Int{
                animateCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve.
            }
```

However, animateCurve, being a UIViewAnimationCurve, cannot be converted from an Int. How do I get the curve this way?

If I treat them as numbers, not UIViewAnimationCurve enums, the below errors when attempting to animate:

```
//Animated done button with keyboard
        origDoneFrame = btnDone.frame
        btnDone.hidden = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            animateDuration,
            delay: Numbers.ANIMATE_DELAY,
            options: nil,
            animations: {
                UIView.setAnimationCurve(animateCurve)
                self.btnDone.frame = CGRectMake(self.btnDone.frame.origin.x + kbHeight, self.btnDone.frame.origin.y, self.btnDone.frame.size.width, self.btnDone.frame.size.height)
                return Void()
            },
            completion: {finished in
                return Void()
            }
        )
```

Is there a way to set the curve using an int?

Attempted int curve with:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(
            animateDuration,
            delay: Numbers.ANIMATE_DELAY,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions(animateCurve << 16),
            animations: {
                self.btnDone.frame = CGRectMake(self.btnDone.frame.origin.x + kbHeight, self.btnDone.frame.origin.y, self.btnDone.frame.size.width, self.btnDone.frame.size.height)
                return Void()
            },
            completion: {finished in
                return Void()
            }
        )
```

But compile error occurs due to UIViewAnimationOptions not being correct type. If I run the assignment of UIViewAnimationOptions on it's own, I get the compiler error "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments."

Comment: Have you tried using `as? UIViewAnimationCurve` instead?

Comment: @IanMacDonald That does not compile. The error is something that doesn't pretain tot he actual issue (as I've noticed is often the case with XCode, but the 7 doesn't match to an enum (see nickgraef's response below)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get an enum value from the raw `Int` value with

```
animateCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: kbCurve)
```

However, the standard keyboard uses an animation curve value of 7, which might not match up with an enum value, so `animateCurve` would be `nil`. If this is the case, just define `animateCurve` as an `Int` and use the raw values in your code rather than the enum values.

Additionally, a quick Google search turned up this wrapper, which might be useful to you: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/13d5f18b0d56b0ea9242

**Update to answer edited question:**

You can use an integer animation curve value in the animation options by converting it to a `UIViewAnimationOptions` value:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions(kbCurve << 16)  // where kbCurve: UInt
```

**Update for Swift 1.2 (XCode 6.3):**

The release notes for Swift 1.2 indicate that NS_ENUM types with undocumented values can now be converted from their raw integer values without being reset to nil. So the following code will now work:

```
let animateCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue)!
```

**Update for Swift 2.2 (XCode 7.3):**

```
if let animationCurveInt = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.unsignedIntegerValue {
  let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveInt<<16)
  ...
}
```

Comment: You are correct. 7 does not match up with an enum. However, when I attempt to do the above (see edited post), it errors on UIView.setAnimationCurve.

Comment: @steventnorris I've updated my answer to show how you can use the 7 value as an animation curve.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but got a compiler error. I've adjusted the post above.

Comment: @steventnorris You need to bit shift `kbCurve` (an Int), not `animateCurve` (an enum value)

Comment: animateCurve in this case is an Int. I should have clarified that. I used UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut.rawValue to get my default Int value.

Comment: @steventnorris Ah ok, `animateCurve` actually needs to be a `UInt`, not `Int`. My bad.

Comment: How do you do it in Swift 2?

Comment: @NicolasMiari updated for Swift 2+ - I used a "if let" above but in my real code I use guard.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version:

```
if let curveValue = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.uintValue {
    let curveAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curveValue << 16)
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an older API, non-block based one. Then you will be able to set animation curve, which you will obtain from notification object.